# Deserializing int& type with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to upgrade dependencies of a legacy code base to use protobuf-net 2.3.7 instead of protobuf-net 1.0

The following code used to work with version 1 and prints `2147483647`

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, int.MaxValue, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
stream.Position = 0;

Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, _ => typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), out var lastItem);
Console.WriteLine(lastItem);
```

But the same code doesn't work with protobuf-net 2.3.7 and throws:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Type is not
>   expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Int32&    at
>   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowUnexpectedType(Type type)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoReader
>   reader, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Type type, Object& value,
>   Boolean skipOtherFields, Boolean asListItem, Boolean autoCreate,
>   Boolean insideList, Object parentListOrType)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream source,
>   Object value, Type type, PrefixStyle style, Int32 expectedField,
>   TypeResolver resolver, Int64& bytesRead, Boolean& haveObject,
>   SerializationContext context)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream
>   source, PrefixStyle style, TypeResolver resolver, Object& value)

Although the exception makes sense I am trying to find a way to make the code to work with the new version of the library without doing a massive refactoring.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

`MemoryStream` contains 8 bytes after serialization: 
`new byte[] {10,6,8,255,255,255,255,7}`

base64: `CgYI/////wc=`

Comment: Wow, that's an edge case! Do you happen to know what bytes that used to serialize as? I.e. the hex or base-64 of the output?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have added the stream output to the question now.

Comment: thanks; that data makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has never been a specifically designed scenario, and frankly I'm amazed that it ever worked, even in 1.something, but: this seems to work:

```
Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, _ => typeof(int), out var lastItem);
 Console.WriteLine(lastItem); // lastItem is a boxed int
```

Is there a specific reason you want a wrapped pointer?

Comment: We needed a wrapped pointer because of our custom RPC layer. Whenever a request is to be made, we pack arguments into a message and serialize it, and do the same for the response message. When we are deserializing the response message, we use reflection and get types of arguments. There are two unit tests that fail after the upgrade because they are specifically testing the serialization/deserialization of `ref int` and `out int` arguments. Thanks for the answer!